# Accessing Hashmap values from another class

Tags: java

I have created 3 HashMaps in a Database class. And I want to check for a certain value in a hashmap before adding an item. So I want to check my Retailer HashMap for a specific value, and if that value exists, I add certain items. 
I'm not sure how to call the hashmap from another class or how to code that loop, where am I going wrong?

My HashMap creation:

```
private static Map<Long, User> users = new HashMap<>();
private static Map<Long, Retailer> retailers = new HashMap<>();
private static Map<Long, Item> items = new HashMap<>();
```

My method to create an item/items:

```
public ItemService(){

    items.put(1l, new Item(1, "Black Suit Shoes", "Black" , "11"));
    items.put(2l, new Item(2, "Nike Runners", "Red" , "7"));
    items.put(3l, new Item(3, "Nike Sports Socks", "Yellow" , "4"));
}
```

I want to make sure a retailer with a specific Id exists, and if it does, then add these items.

Comment: Make it public static.

Comment: ... or make getters for them

Comment: ... or add a public method that does what you want done.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Add a public method in my Database class or in the ItemService class? and what would the loop that calls the HashMap look like?

Comment: You have the `containsKey` method to check if a key exists. Just encapsulate the logic you want in a method.

Comment: @Isac - the problem is I'm unsure how to do that!

Comment: How are you adding the items ? Would you pass the array of items to add if the retailer exists ? As an `Item[]` ? That is not very clear in the question

Comment: @Isac The second piece of code: "ItemService" is adding the items. Ideally I'd like to create an ArrayList of Items as well as Retailers. And if a Retailer exists in the List, then we add items to the ArrayList while relating them to that Retailer. I'm just unsure how this process works

Comment: The problem is what the `Long`s  mean in your maps and how do they relate between each other. Also there's a potential problem about repeated `Item` ids for the received Items to add

Comment: @Isac so it's a no go then? Or is there a way to work around it? And we're only storing the entries locally, so duplicate ID's etc are of no concern.

Comment: I can post an answer with what i was saying but it probably won't fit your needs because you didn't clarify how you are using the ids(Longs), Items, etc... How do the ids in those 3 lists relate to each other ? How do you guarantee that you aren't adding items with the same id into the items map ? Also you didn't make it clear how do you plan to add the items, if you are adding one by one or an array of items.

Comment: @Isac At the moment, we're not using those Longs for anything, they're autogenerated Id's when we run the ItemService method. And I'd like to have it so that items are linked to certain Retailers, as a ManyToOne, and Retailers and Users are OneToOne.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a specific key exists in a `Map` you can use the [`containsKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)) method. You didn't make it clear how the `Item` ids are generated but i will assume that they are unique.

Considering that you could do the following to add an item:

```
public boolean addItemsIfRetailerExists(Long retailerId, Item item){
    if (!retailers.containsKey(retailerId)){
        return false;
    }

    items.put(item.id, item);
    return true;
}
```

Note that this implies calling the method with the `Item` you want to insert:

```
addItemsIfRetailerExists(5341l, new Item(1, "Black Suit Shoes", "Black" , "11"));
```

To add more functionality i added a `boolean` `return` value which indicates if the item was inserted or not.

You could even create an overload for this method that would receive an `Item` array instead to be able to add multiple items at once:

```
public boolean addItemsIfRetailerExists(Long retailerId, Item[] itemsToAdd){
    if (!retailers.containsKey(retailerId)){
        return false;
    }

    for(Item i:itemsToAdd){
        items.put(i.id, i);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Which you can now call with all the items you want to add:

```
addItemsIfRetailerExists(5341l, new Item[] { 
    new Item(1, "Black Suit Shoes", "Black" , "11"),
    new Item(2, "Nike Runners", "Red" , "7"),
    new Item(3, "Nike Sports Socks", "Yellow" , "4")});
```